# Receiver app not being triggered?

Tags: google-cast

I'm trying to run the sample Hello Text android app. The app builds fine and runs on my phone (Note 2) but after my speech is recognized a toast it displayed with whatever I spoke and next I think the app should cast the text to my Chromecast. I can see my dev device in the drop down list and select it but after speaking the receiver app never launches. Does anyone else have experience with this issue? I'm using Android Studio.

EDIT(Solution):

The libraries were not added to the project correctly. Subsequently, 
`@integer/google_play_services_version` in `androidManifest.xml wasn't being found. Troubleshooting that issue I hardcoded the version number in like so:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="4030500" />`
```

After fixing the libraries and changing the above back to:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`
```

it worked perfectly. So yes, I did change the code.

Comment: Does the receiver app launch on the TV when you select your cast device?

Comment: No it doesn't. I can select my device but nothing happens after I select it.

Comment: Have you changed the sender code in any way other than using your own app id? Have you tried to restart your Chromecast device?

Comment: No, I don't believe I've changed anything. I did try to restart my device. Possibly unrelated: When I'm casting Netflix and connect to the same device in the sample app I can change the chromecast's volume with the slider but it never stops netflix and starts the sample app.